# Interpreting uncertainties in calculated slope and $y$-intercept

Tags: slope, mathematical-astronomy

I'm trying to interpret the slope and $y$-intercept of a rather specific equation.  The equation I'm dealing with is 
$$R = C\left(\frac{L}{10^{44}\text{ erg s}^{-1}}\right)^\alpha$$
taking the base-10 logarithm of both sides, I get 
$$\log_{10}(R) = \left[\log_{10}(C)-\alpha\log_{10}(10^{44})\right]+\alpha\log_{10}(L)=K+\alpha\log_{10}(L)$$
also known as the Radius-Luminosity relation for supermassive black holes in astrophysics, and is linear in log space.  The best-fit values for the $y$-intercept $K$ and slope $\alpha$, with their quoted uncertainties, are given by 
$$K=-21.3^{+2.9}_{-2.8}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\alpha=0.519^{+0.063}_{-0.066}$$.  Therefore the coefficient $C$ in the first equation is given by 
$$C = 10^{K+\alpha\log_{10}{10^{44}}}$$

Plugging in the values for $K$ and $\alpha$ yield a value of $C=34.36$.   I would like to determine the maximum and minimum values for the coefficient $C$ given the maximum and minimum possible values for the $y$-intercept and slope $\alpha$.  I do not think it is as simple as plugging in $K\pm\delta k$ and $\alpha\pm\delta\alpha$ (the values which would maximize/minimize $C$), since this would produce unrealistic upper and lower limits to $C$ ($10^{7.208}$ and $10^{-4.168}$ respectively).

Instead I think the value of the slope determines the uncertainty in the $y$-intercept.  That is to say a higher value of $\alpha$ corresponds to a lower value of $K$.  This makes sense; if we increase the slope the $y$-intercept gets shifted down.  Then if the maximum value of $\alpha$ corresponds to the lowest value for $K$, I get $C=32.21$ for a minimum value of $C$, and vice-versa, taking lowest possible value for $\alpha$ and the highest possible value for $K$, I get $C=34.04$ for a maximum(?) value for $C$.

So my maximum value for $C$ is still less than my optimal value of $C=34.36$.  Obviously I did something wrong but I can't figure out what.

Is there a way to determine the maximal and minimal values of $C$ from $\alpha$ and $K$? And if so, how?

Comment: Pay attention that , upon taking the log, you end with a $K(\alpha)$

Comment: It would be interesting to get your feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write $LogR=LogC+\alpha(LogL-44)$ and do the linear regression on that